# return a list of objects from firebase/flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've a collection in Firebase. I return a stream with this code:

```
Stream<List<T>> collectionStream<T>({
    @required String path,
    @required T builder(Map<String, dynamic> data),
  }) {
    final reference = Firestore.instance.collection(path);
    final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
    return snapshots.map((snapshot) =>
        snapshot.documents.map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data)).toList());
  }
}
```

How can I return `List<T>`. I don't need a stream. I need a list of my objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .single getter method of the Stream returned from collectionStream to get a Future:

```
Stream<List<Bookmark>> bookmarkStream = collectionStream<Bookmark>(...);
```

...

```
List<Bookmark> singleList = await bookmarkStream.single;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
```

you should do

```
final _docs = reference.getDocuments();
```

This will return a QuerySnapshot that contains a List in `_docs.documents`.

Then you can iterate over that List and get the data you need to map it to your classes.